# How should be the order of perfect tense in "what" questions?

Tags: present-perfect, word-order, questions

I am confused about order in the following sentences. Which one is correct?

> What changes **you have** made?

or

> What changes **have you** made?

Answer (score 1):

If there is an auxiliary verb, which in this case is 'have,' the verb goes ahead to the pronoun.

So,

> What changes ***have you*** made?

[More on that is here.](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/question-forms-subjectobject-questions)